# minimal polynomial of $(2^{1/3}+3^{1/4})^{12}$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Is there an elegant way to find the minimal polynomial of $(2^{1/3}+3^{1/4})^{12}$ over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Since the constant term of that polynomial is $3\,138\,428\,376\,721$, I seriously doubt that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but 3 138 428 376 721=11^12, which doesn't sound too wierd...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: at least, is there an elegant way to find out the extension degree ?

Comment: I don't know one.